# How do I troubleshoot the "Error, press shutter release button again" message on my Nikon?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, shutter, shutter-release, error

The LCD on my Nikon D3000 is displaying the following error message:

> Error. Press shutter release button again.

I have pressed the shutter release button but the camera still does not work.

Comment: You meant: "Error. Press shutter release button again." This is a fairly common issue with many Nikon DSLR cameras, and it usually indicates a mechanical problem with the shutter or mirror unit.  It is most prevalent with the D40, D40x, and D60, but can occur with newer models as well.

Answer (score 2):

Many possibilities, so little time. Several things to check. Usually needs to be returned to Nikon for repairs if error message repeats.

1. Is the battery charged?
2. Remove battery for a few hours/overnight then replace.
3. Remove and replace lens or put a different lens on camera.
4. Remove and replace memory card or put a different memory card in camera.
5. Is viewfinder dark? Mirror may be stuck up. **At your own risk** *gently* use a toothpick or something that won't scratch the camera internals to urge the mirror back down.

Again, if all else fails return to Nikon...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to BobT's suggestions, if all else fails you may want to try removing the bottom plate of the camera and lubricating the gear wheels that drive the shutter. This is a fairly common issue and isn't near as hard as it sounds.

http://jacko0.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/d40x-underside/

Of course, I wouldn't attempt this with a camera under warranty, but if it past the warranty period and you're mechanically inclined, give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add from recent experience on a Nikon D40x that after 4-5 years of good work started showing the message "Error, press shutter release button again" (or similar).  I followed advice on the net to remove the bottom cap, oil the wheels and 'unblock' the shutter release motor.  It worked but for a very limited number of takes.  Did it again, worked, got stuck again, to the point we were carrying around with us a small screwdriver so we could fix it on the spot!  Not practical.
Went to EBay and bought a new shutter release motor (6-7 Euro) but when I tried to fit it the task became too complicated for my limited tools and knowledge... However I did reach the box that holds the plastic wheels the motor moves and unscrewed it to try to release the motor.  When I decided to close the camera back on (hoping not to have too many spare screws after closing the case...) I screwed the box with the plastic wheels linked to the shutter speed motor but perhaps not as tightly as they were before.
The result was that since I closed the camera we have taken more than 1000 pictures without ever having the error message.
I think that the trick was loosing the screws in the plastic box where the wheels are...
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased a Nikon D3200 a week ago and have taken 400 shots using the standard 18-55 lens without any problem. I then purchased a used DX VR-S 18-135mm, and all seemed fine in full auto mode, but then I changed to manual (which I prefer) and got the error message `error press shutter release again`.

I fully zoomed the lens and took another shot, and it worked fine; retracted the lens again and once again got the error message. I removed the lens and replaced it with my 18-55 kit lens and have taken a couple of hundred shots with no problem. My advice would be to try different lens before dismantling your camera. Although, I am sure, looking at most forums, most of the time it is a case of fixing gear wheel in the body.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once.

There is nothing you can do except give it for servicing at an authorized service center. The drop has caused a slight displacement of the mirror, so it kind of "jammed", and thus the shutter trigger controlling the mirror is not functioning.

My camera was in my camera bag and fell from a meter high and this was the result. You don't have to worry, your camera is not permanently broken, and will shoot as it used to without any problem.

Answer (score -2):

Google it and instructable.com.  It is a fairly simple operation and you are not alone.  No need to try to replace a motor.  It just need lubrication to a gear.  Seven screws I believe, A little WD40, sprayed through a stencil and you're too go.

I'm getting ready to open mine up now.  Use some duct tape to keep up with the screws.

Comment: WAIT!!  Not WD40.  The WD stands for Water Displacement, and that stuff can get around through your whole camera.  Just use some grease.