# Nikon D5000 error with shutter release and mirror staying up

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, shutter, mirror

When I take a photo on my Nikon D5000, it comes up with an error "press shutter release button again". When I do that, it gives me the same error, and my pictures turn black. Also, when I take my lens off, the mirror is stuck up.

[image: error message]

Comment: @Hueco Why should the mirror be up when the lens is removed?

Comment: Black pictures are usually because they are underexposed. I don't see anything in the OP about bulb mode or mirror lockup.

Comment: Related: [Why do I get the “Press Shutter Release Button Again” error when my D3200 isn't set to max. aperture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/77015/15871) and [Nikon D90 mirror stuck](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/74780/15871)

Answer (score 0):

Check the viewfinder for some kind of error code, I had the same issue with my D80, and there was just ERR message, if the same will happen to you, the DSLR will need to see a repair shop.